# Forward an HTTP client certificate through SSH

Tags: git, ssh, client-certificates

I have a git repository for which the only way to access is via HTTPS using HTTP client certificates. This works just fine on my local machine when doing `git clone`, `git push`, etc.

I also want to do this on a remote machine that I access via SSH, but I cannot put my client certificates on the remote machine. Is there a way to forward HTTP client certificates in a similar way as SSH-agent forwarding.

Comment: The TLS client certificate must be kept on your local machine, with the associated secret key. What you ask is against the recommended TLS client certificate usage.

Comment: can you please include a reference that indicates this is not recommended?

Comment: What is not recommended is put the private key of the client certificate on a machine where others could read it.

Comment: o right. i understand that. That's the point of the question. How do i do forwarding such that I don't need to put the private key of the client cert on the remote machine? I can accomplish this with ssh keys using `ssh -A`. how do I do it with http client certs? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Git requires that the client certificates be on the local file system, since it has no way to read them from elsewhere (except the system credential store, and then only on some operating systems in some configurations).

It's possible that you could connect back from the remote machine to your laptop using something like sshfs if they're on the same network, and mount a portion of your local file system with the certificates as a network file system.  You could also try doing the clone on your local machine instead of the remote machine and then pushing to the remote machine (after setting `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead` on the remote repository).

Beyond that, there isn't a way to do what you want.